# how we can apply if else condition on css properties using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to put condition on CSS properties in JavaScript. What is the easiest way to do this?

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>TOOLTIP USING JAVASCRIPT</title> 
    <style>
        span{
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        #demo{
            background-color:cadetblue;
            color:white;
            width:150px;
            padding:10px;
            font-size:12px;
            position:absolute;
            top:20px;
            left:60px;
            display:none;
        }
    </style>
    <link href="font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>

<body>
    <br><br><br><br>

    <label for='name'>NAME </label>
    <span id="s1" style="color:#00b1ff;font-size:15px" class="fa fa-info-circle">&nbsp;:</span>

    <p id="demo">Please Enter Only Characters</p>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter The Name ">

<script type="text/javascript">

if(con.style.display="none")  
{
code here....
}

</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if(con.style.display="none") { code here.... }
 HOW WE CAN DO THIS IN JAVSCRIPT

Comment: Stop >>SHOUTING<<!  You might in the army (per your image) ... but we are civilian, and we don't respond to being shouted at by angry military types.

Comment: Please read [how to create a minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for better results using this site.

Answer (score 2):

use javascript `getComputedStyle` & `getPropertyValue` property.

## HTML

```
<div id="conditionals">Change this text here</div>
```

## CSS

```
#conditionals {
display: none;
}
```

## Javascript

```
var element = document.getElementById("conditionals");
var compStyle = window.getComputedStyle(element);
var prop = compStyle.getPropertyValue('display');

alert(prop);
```

Now you will get the prop value to be none and use if/else conditions to show manipulate the css and html

```
if(prop) {
/**code here **/
}
else {
/** code here **/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x= $('.yourSelector').css('display');
    if (x == 'none') {
        //Your code.....
    }
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x= $('.x').css('display');
    if (x == 'none') {
        alert('display is None');
    }

    else {
        alert('display is not none')
    }
})
```

```css
.x {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<div class="x"></div>
```